# Xcode ruby runscript can not find gem

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, build-error, run-script

Xcode: 9.3.1

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

I am and iOS developer and I am not familiar with ruby at all.

I am using a run-script in my Xcode project which uses a ruby gem called '`xcodeproj`'. Before everything was working, But I updated my macOS and now this runscript is not able to find gem 'xcodeproj'

When I try to build my project it shows following error

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I went to the path which is shown in the above error, and there was no `xcodeproj` gem files, even after that I installed `gem install xcodeproj` it is being installed somewhere else. This is the output on my terminal

```html
xxx-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

atomos (0.1.2)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
bundler (default: 1.16.1)
CFPropertyList (3.0.0)
claide (1.0.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
colored2 (3.1.2)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
date (default: 1.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
nanaimo (0.2.5)
openssl (default: 2.1.0)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
xcodeproj (1.5.9)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

Moreover, when I try to execute my ruby runscript via terminal it shows no error (And via xcode it fails).

Apparently, gem `xcodeproj` has been installed in my macOS but it is not under Ruby.framwork and I think that's why my xcode's runscript is failing at build time. Hese is my runscript  [image]

The screenshot of error in Xcode [image]

Any help is highly appreciated, guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the bug in my code.

There were two ruby versions one for the system i.e `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3` (this is for the root system, which comes with macOS) and other was `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby` (Not sure what is this for, My guess is that it is separate ruby environment for new version 2.5.1, I might have installed it in past)

In my runscript's shell, I had `/usr/bin/ruby` which has ruby executable file for system's ruby `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework`

I checked the ruby environment by command `gem environment`, And it gave the output

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/xxx/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
```

Here `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin` and I had a different path for my ruby executable which I specified in my runscript's shell `(/usr/bin/ruby)` so I changed `/usr/bin/ruby` to `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and it is working.

As my gem was being installed in updated version of ruby(2.5) `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby` instead of old system's ruby (2.3)`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework` so now as I provided the executable ruby path of the latest ruby version, in which gem was installed, it is working fine.